# Sqlite subtract different rows from different columns

Tags: sqlite, rows, window-functions, offset, subtraction

Let's say that I have sql table like this:

```
id | val_1 | val_2
1  | 55    |  300
2  | 90    |  600
3  | 80    |  200
..
```

Now, I wan't to subtract 300-90, and next 600-80 and so on with offset of one row. Table can be odd count like this. Is there a chance to do this without loop and external functions? I use Python api for sqlite3.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the output that you want you can use `LEAD()` window function:

```
SELECT *, 
       val_2 - LEAD(val_1, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS difference
FROM tablename;
```

or `LAG()` window function:

```
SELECT *, 
       LAG(val_2, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id) - val_1 AS difference
FROM tablename;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0b1ace8a411bc7e01cabfa88f0a041a2).

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you :)